# Android Build Failed in Running the Project While Building APK Works Fine

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have got a new mac from the company and cloned the project from the Git. Works fine on my Windows PC.

However it fails on the mac with this message:

```
Error:org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with path 'dexBetaDebug' not found in project ':app'.
```

Cleaning, rebuilding, and building APK works fine but when I want to run it on my device, it fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, `dexBetaDebug` isn't a default Gradle task, so sounds like you've not downloaded something correctly

Comment: beta is a product flavor, debug is a build type in my project. I hope this means something to find the solution.

Comment: Please show the Gradle file(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked deep into gradle logs and saw Crashlytics causes the problem, and ridicolously solved the problem by setting fabric dependency version speficially in app gradle.

Problematic code was like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

I solved it by changing it like this:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.6'
```

It is really disappointing that the recent version of fabric causes the problem.